# Can I save image created in PowerPoint as a printable vector?

Tags: print-design

I was asked to create a logo to be printed on a large number of t-shirts for an event. I designed the logo in PowerPoint using text, shapes and a .png image. The people from the printing company said that they need it in vector format (corel, adobe illustrator or editable pdf). I exported the logo as a .emf / .pdf file, but they say the image is still bitmap and they need it in vector file. Is there a way to export the image from PowerPoint so that they can print it?

Comment: Did you add any text effects like glow? If all you did was write text and or place objects without effects and exported to a PDF. Then the graphic will be in vector format. If you apply effects, then they might be rasterized. I am not sure if all effects get rasterized, I just tested with outer glow.

Comment: I do not mean to be rude but that process is **totally wrong**; the usage of power point, a png. If it is a large event, it would be a lot better if **a profesional designer design the T shirt, or a large number of T shirts will be wasted**. A good design is an investment.

Answer (score 3):

While EMF and PDF can both be vector formats, you say that your logo contains a PNG image. PNG is a raster image format, so when you export to PDF or EMF, you'll have a vector image with an *embedded* PNG. This is probably the issue your printer is having.

You cannot simply convert a raster graphic like a PNG file to a vector graphic by saving it as a vector format. You will need to either 1.) re-create the PNG aspects as a vector or 2.) use an application like Adobe Illustrator to trace it.

If you are looking for a free program for vector graphics, I'd recommend [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/). Inkscape does have limited tracing abilities, although your mileage will vary depending on your image.

[I feel that I have a moral duty to tell you that **PowerPoint is not for drawing things**. PowerPoint is for making dreadfully boring slideshows with cheesy star-swipe transitions and clip art circa 1998. **Use the appropriate tool for a job.** Use Inkscape, Illustrator, or even LibreOffice Draw to make your logo; use PowerPoint for the Annual Q4 Sales Working Group Planning Meeting presentation.]

Comment: Actually powerpoint is probably the most used vector drawing program out there. Ive seen many a fine drawing made with powerpoint. Offcoure it lacks cmyk mode and users of powerpoint rarely know what they are doing, which ruins many works, not PP itself. Not that i would use it because it has a horrible scaling problem. But overall it works fine as long as you distill PDF files (And do not use native export) and actually know what your doing, by which time you either avoid it or simplify your workflow. PS: you can paste artwork from PP to illustrator directly and vice versa

Comment: @joojaa you are right that PowerPoint *can* be used for good drawings, and my assessment is a bit tongue-in-cheek. A good designer can make good work regardless of the tool, in the same way that a good wood-worker could make a nice chess piece out of a block of cedar and a flat head screw driver. Just because you *can* do it doesn't make the tool any more appropriate.

Comment: What other reason is there? I mean i made a font with a text editor, because I can. I draw 3D objects in illustrator (instead of any of my 3D cads that would do the same in quarter of the time) because i can. I build my own screencapture software and pedal because i can. It do t have to make sense. ;)

Comment: I agree with Scribblemacher. Power Point is a presentation tool. It may be possible to draw with it, but the point is, it's not a design tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you design a vector image in PowerPoint using tools like text and shapes, as long as you do not apply any shadows, blur, gradient, beveling, etc, you can export as a PDF and it will export as a vector.

Any effects you apply are exported as raster. Without effects, your PDF can be opened in Inkscape (free) or Adobe Illustrator and edited like any other vector graphic.

Also please note that your PNG is a raster graphic, and if you used it in your design, this part of your logo will not export as a vector.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Drawing with PowerPoint]

I disagree PowerPoint is not used for drawing. I created these characters using PowerPoint, using the Line tool and other shapes, adding the background from Pixabay.